# Where are God's lab and God's own thesis written on whole universe development?

Tags: universe

I am not sure about exact meta branch on this question. but I ask it in Hinduism context.

Question is:

Every scientist does some experiement for any kind of invention in lab and writes thesis on it.

Where are God's lab for experiment and God's own thesis written on whole universe development?

Comment: Why are you comparing God with minimal and insignificant creatures like human beings. God needs not perform any action to bring into existence or inexistence something. Devi creates and destroys this universe by mere opening and closing of Her eyelids. ShaarngaDhara destroyes and creates this universe by mere inhaling and exhaling. TriNayana has a mere will and this universe is comes and passes like a blink of His eyes. The Supreme God does not even have any Form, and does not need to decide act like an ordinary human being testing samples in conical flask in a laboratory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally believe that one should ask questions. Arjuna did and that's how we got **Bhagavad Gita**. Your question is very valid and deserves an answer.

I will quote two separate sources and try to summarize in the simplest way possible where to look for God's lab and his thesis :)

**Manu-Smriti**

[image: Manu Smriti Chapter 1]

> Even before nothing existed, there was the supreme soul ('God' as most
>   of us refer him). At some point, he manifested himself into basic
>   elements and properties. And with his (creative) power those elements made up
>   everything that our senses can perceive and beyond.

**Bhagavad Gita**

[image: Bhagavad Gita 1]

> However different things look, everything material and non-material
>   has originated from the same supreme soul and some day will merge back
>   into the same.

[image: Bhagavad Gita 2]

**Summary**

Coal, diamond and food we eat are all forms of carbon. This simple analogy builds the premise to understand that everything you can perceive from Stars to Flowers is some form of the supreme soul. The soul of everything (**Brahman**, as the scriptures call it.)

**Where is his laboratory?**
13.5 billion light years of observable universe is one setup in his laboratory. There can be infinite more setups which we cannot perceive. (Look up 'Multiverse')

**Where is his thesis?**
The supreme soul himself is the scientist, the experiment, the outcomes and the thesis.

Comment: Really great answer

Comment: Really good content and source! Thank you. 